# java: Merging objects

Tags: java

I need to merge 2 objects into 1. Eg I have:

```
Object obj1=new Object();
Object obj2=new Object();
```

I need to merge obj1 and obj2 into 1.

Comment: The exact same answer has been delete a while ago. If you don't specify in **much** more detail what you want to achieve, this one will find a similar end.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Object1 and Object2 are a) of the same type and b) java bean compatible, you could use [Commons / BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) like this:

```
Map<String, Object> beanMap1 = BeanUtils.describe(object1);
Map<String, Object> beanMap2 = BeanUtils.describe(object2);
// now merge beanMap1 into beanMap2
Object merged = new YourCustomObject();
BeanUtils.populate(beanMap2, merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a third object:

```
Object thirdObject = new Object();
```

and extract the information you need from `obj1` and `obj2` and insert into `thirdObject`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by merge. You cannot just merge two objects. However, you can create a composite objects out of the two objects you have.